# Name of Particular Constrained Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, terminology, linear-programming, constraints

I am writing to ask if any of you know what is the name in the research literature of a particular constrained optimization problem I am facing. I would like to find a general name so that I can research better on the matter.

The problem in question is:

I have P persons that need to be assigned to T tasks (P>>T). Each person can be assigned to only one task. A particular person p_i has a different score (ability) to complete a task t_i. To simplify, let's assume the score distribution for each person p_i is a probability distribution over the tasks (sum to 1). Moreover, each task t_i has a precise capacity C_t_i which is the number of persons that must be assigned to the task. Pay attention that sum of C_t_i over i equals P so that all people can be assigned to one task. I want to find a feasible solution that maximizes the score.

- P persons
- T tasks
- p_i must be assigned to only one task
- t_i has a capacity C_t_i of people which must be assigned to t_i
- sum_over_i (C_t_i) = P

This can be visualized in a matrix S (score matrix). Find in the table below an example of score matrix S:

```
----------------------------
|   \  T | t_1 | t_2 | t_3 |
| P  \   |     |     |     |
----------------------------
| p_1    | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.7 | -> sum to 1
| p_2    | 0.9 | 0.1 | 0   | -> sum to 1
| p_3    | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.8 |
| p_4    | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.3 |
| p_5    | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
----------------------------
| C      | 1   | 2   | 2   |
----------------------------
```

A feasible solution to the example is the following matrix, let's call it X:

```
----------------------------
|   \  T | t_1 | t_2 | t_3 |
| P  \   |     |     |     |
----------------------------
| p_1    | 1   | 0   | 0   |
| p_2    | 0   | 1   | 0   |
| p_3    | 0   | 0   | 1   |
| p_4    | 0   | 1   | 0   |
| p_5    | 0   | 0   | 1   |
----------------------------
| C      | 1   | 2   | 2   |
----------------------------
```

Which has a overall score of 0.1+0.1+0.8+0.4+0.6=2. There is of course a better solution with a higher score.

The problem can be re-written in mathematical formulas such as:

```
find matrix X
maximizing sum_over_i_j ( X.S ) for every i in rows and j in columns
such that sum_over_j (X_i) = 1 for every i in rows and j in columns
and sum_over_i (X_j) = C_t_j for every i in rows and j in columns
```

Where . is the point-wise multiplication between matrices.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [transportation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)).  The people are the supply nodes, with a supply of $1$ unit each.  The tasks are the demand nodes, with demand C_t_i.  The usual formulation has a minimization objective, but you can negative the objective function for maximization.